# Order of Proving inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

in sometime when i proving inequalities
Example
For positive a,b,c,d and $abcd=16$
Show that $(\frac{a}{b})^3+(\frac{b}{c})^{3}+(\frac{c}{d})^3+(\frac{d}{a})^3+4 \geq a+b+c+d $

My proof But can't end....

First L.H.S use power mean inequalities we'll get

$ L.H.S \geq (\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a}}{16})^{3}+4 $
 And R.H.S. i multiply with $\frac{2}{\sqrt[4]{abcd}}$ Now inequality is Homogenous i'll ignore condition abcd=16

We need to prove that $(\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a}}{16})^{3}+4 \geq \frac{2(a+b+c+d)}{\sqrt[4]{abcd}}$

From A.M.-G.M ; $\sum_{cyc}
\frac{a}{b} \geq 4$.... So in the end

I got $4\sqrt[4]{abcd} \geq a+b+c+d $ but following with wrong reverse sign  ....

So now is have some trick about what should do first in proving inequality ? A.M-G.M or Cauchy  ..... i.e
Thanks !

Comment: That's the thing about inequalities. Especially for non-symmetric ones, there is no guarantee that a particular technique must work. You have to try various ones, and use your experience to guess at what could work.